# Проблемы с кодировкой

Tags: html

Когда я делаю кодировку utf-8, переводит все символы, кроме переданных значений с другой страницы. А когда делаю страницу windows-1251", то наоборот переводит только переданные?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

все страницы переведи в utf-8, и лучше через какой-нибудь специализированный редактор, например http://www.ankord.com/ru/phpxedit.php работает со всеми типами файлов в том числе и html, и неплохо перекодирует!